# Java method not doing what expected. Trying to understand why

Tags: java

Trying to write a java method that will take a string, loop through it and where it finds a vowel (A,E,I,O,U,Y) replace it with the vowel plus "OB".

I've written the below but it isn't working as I'd expect and doesn't seem to be matching the current character in my string with the vowels from my list. (The program compiles and runs so it isn't an issue with not importing necessary bits at the beginning. The input string will always be uppercase and only contain alphas.) I'm struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone help?

```
public static String obifyText(String text) {

    String[] myList = new String[] {"A","E","I","O","U","Y"};
    StringBuilder tempText = new StringBuilder(text);
    String obify = "OB";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() -1 ; i ++ ) {
        if ( Arrays.asList(myList).contains(tempText.charAt(i)) ) {
            System.out.println(tempText.charAt(i)+" found.");
            tempText = tempText.insert((i+1),obify);
        }
    }

    text = tempText.toString();
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs, and the values your method returns when given those inputs, and the expected values returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't play with indexes.

Managing with indexes could be difficult when you are dealing with changing the string.

Loop on the `char`s itself as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] myList = new String[] {"A","E","I","O","U","Y"};
    String text = "AEE";
    StringBuilder tempText = new StringBuilder("");
    String obify = "OB";
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()){
        tempText = tempText.append(c);
        if ( Arrays.asList(myList).contains(c+"") ) {
            System.out.println(c+" found.");
            tempText = tempText.append(obify);
        }
    }

    text = tempText.toString();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
A found.
E found.
E found.
AOBEOBEOB
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare two different types in `Arrays.asList(myList).contains(tempText.charAt(i))`, `Arrays.asList(myList)` is a `List<String>` and `tempText.charAt` is a `char`. So the contains check will never result in true.

One possible fix, change myList to `Character[]`

```
Character[] myList = new Character[] {'A','E','I','O','U','Y'};
```

There is another problem with the actual insertion, see Pankaj Singhal answer for a solution to that.

Comment: This won't work. The problem is in the indexes if 2 vowels occur together. Run your code and check.

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` returns a `char`, but `myList` stores `String` elements. An array of `String`s can never `contain` values of `char`. Your if statement never runs.

You can convert the `char` value to a string:

```
Arrays.asList(myList).contains(Character.toString(tempText.charAt(i)))
```

There's just one more problem with your code.

When the code inserts `OB` after a vowel, there is a side effect: a new vowel O is created. Your code then tries to insert `OB` after the new `O`. This is undesired, right?

To make it not do this, you can loop from the end of the string to the start:

```
for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
```

---

If this is not a homework question to practice using `StringBuilder` or for loops, here's a one liner solution using regex:

```
return text.replaceAll("([AEIOUY])", "$1OB");
```